# Assigning value to object parameter

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

i have embedded code inside sharepoints. I need to pass a javascript value to a parameter. How can i do this here? Please see 3rd parameters, PUT_FUNCTION_VALUE_HERE for reference purposes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getUrlParameters(parameter, staticURL, decode){
   /*
    Function: getUrlParameters
    Description: Get the value of URL parameters either from 
                 current URL or static URL
    Author: Tirumal
    URL: www.code-tricks.com
   */
   var currLocation = (staticURL.length)? staticURL : window.location.search,
       parArr = currLocation.split("?")[1].split("&"),
       returnBool = true;

   for(var i = 0; i < parArr.length; i++){
        parr = parArr[i].split("=");
        if(parr[0] == parameter){
            return (decode) ? decodeURIComponent(parr[1]) : parr[1];
            returnBool = true;
        }else{
            returnBool = false;            
        }
   }

   if(!returnBool) return false;  
}
function getUrlParametersWrite(parameter, staticURL, decode){
                var vlaue = getUrlParameters(parameter, staticURL, decode);
                alert(value);
                document.write(value);
                document.close();
}

</script>


<script type='text/javascript' src='http://myview.fake.org/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js'></script>
<div class='tableauPlaceholder' style='width: 984px; height: 634px;'>
    <object class='tableauViz' width='984' height='634' style='display:none;'>
        <param name='host_url' value='http://myview.fake.org' /> 
        <param name='site_root' value='' />
        <param name='name' value='MemberParticipationReporting&#47;MemberParticipationDashboard&Fice=PUT_FUNCTION_VALUE_HERE' />
        <param name='tabs' value='yes' />
        <param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
    </object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery this would be very simple.

```
function getUrlParametersWrite(parameter, staticURL, decode){
  var value = getUrlParameters(parameter, staticURL, decode);
  var att = $("param[name='name']").attr("value");
  att = att.replace("PUT_FUNCTION_VALUE_HERE",value);
  $("param[name='host_url']").attr("value",att);
}
```

I am assuming you're trying to set the host_url parameter.

With straight JavaScript this should work:

```
function getUrlParametersWrite(parameter, staticURL, decode){
  var value = getUrlParameters(parameter, staticURL, decode);
  var params = document.getElementsByName("name");
  var att = params[0].getAttribute("value");
  att = att.replace("PUT_FUNCTION_VALUE_HERE",value);
  params[0].setAttribute("value",att);
}
```

Comment: I need to append the value to the end of the following `<param name='name' value='MemberParticipationReporting&#47;MemberParticipationDashboard&Fice=PUT_FUNCTION_VALUE_HERE' />`